# Is it possible to setup a CREATE_LOGON trigger that treats AD Groups differently from users?

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Just started in a DBA role with a new organization and they gave me a bit of a head-scratcher. We've got a trigger on CREATE_LOGON that DENYs VIEW ANY DEFINITION & VIEW ANY DATABASE. This was setup before I joined the organization but I believe it was done in response to some sort of penetration testing. I've been asked to look into editing the trigger to **not** fire when adding logons for AD Groups.

Sample Code

```
USE [master]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [tr_NewLogin] 
ON ALL SERVER 
FOR CREATE_LOGIN
AS 

DECLARE @SQL_Err        INT
DECLARE @data           XML
DECLARE @ObjectType     NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @ObjectName     NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @Value          NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @SQL            NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @LoginName      NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @YN_AD_Group    NCHAR(1)

SET @SQL_Err     = 0
SET @data        = EVENTDATA()
SET @ObjectName  = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'nvarchar(2000)');
SET @LoginName   = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'varchar(500)');
SET @YN_AD_Group = (SELECT TOP 1 CASE sp.type WHEN 'G' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END FROM sys.server_principals sp WHERE @LoginName = sp.name);

BEGIN
    IF @YN_AD_Group = 'N'
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = 'DENY VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO ['+ @ObjectName + ']'
                + ' DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO ['+ @ObjectName + ']'
        PRINT @SQL
        EXECUTE @SQL_Err = sp_Executesql @SQL
    END
END
GO
ENABLE TRIGGER [tr_NewLogin] ON ALL SERVER
GO
```

From looking at the [EVENTDATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eventdata-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) schema, I'm not seeing anything that stands out as a way to definitely tell a login is an AD Group. LoginType only seems to return either SQL Login or Windows NT Login.

Attempting to check sys.server_principals doesn't work either, I'm guessing because that part of the code is being evaluated before the login is added so the data doesn't exist there yet. Is there someway to change when that gets evaluated in the trigger? Or is there some other way to have this trigger not apply to AD Group logins?

**Update 2019-06-19:** Thanks to all the comments on this question and the suggestions for some *interesting* workarounds. I've checked with the original requester of this change. They've decided that while this might be a clever idea; it's not worth exploring odd/kludgy hacks to make it happen. My thanks to those of you who took the time to look over this question.

Comment: I'm sure there are hacky ways to actually accomplish this, but you could go the route of just requiring any AD user to be added via a group (arguably a better way to manage logins anyways) and then you can simply filter on specific groups or SQL Auth logins. I'd just be wary of making an overly complicated trigger tied to logging in.

Comment: @LowlyDBA My understanding is all properly added users are given access via AD Groups. While this trigger is there as a security measure in case somebody manages to get a user account added outside of proper procedures (e.g. using an zero-day exploit to add an account for themselves).

Comment: As you mention, looking at `sys.server_principals` won't work since the login hasn't been created at that point.  The same problem will occur when attempting to run the `DENY` statements.  As it is, this code won't function correctly.

Comment: You *could* create a [Linked Server to Active Directory](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2580/querying-active-directory-data-from-sql-server/) and directly query AD to identify if said account was a user or group and then go from there.  Not exactly something I would recommend, mind you, but if you're looking for kludgy workarounds, this may be an option.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener Thanks for the interesting reading, but that's a bit _too_ kludgy a workaround for us. :)